# websphere, 100% when authenticating against Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, websphere

I've got Websphere 6.0.29 setup to authenticate against Active Directory, but when I log in to my Webapp with a valid user the CPU goes to 100% and doesn't recover, if I log in with an invalid user, then I get a 403 as expected.

There is no clues in the websphere logs.

And I'm stumped as to what the next step should be.

Can anyone suggest where I should look next?
Or has anyone else seen this problem?

Jeff Porter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rick suggested look at the thread dumps to see what is happening when the CPU is at 100%.

It is a good idea to look at Must Gathers for the corresponding scenario. Since you mentioned AD, i am assuming you are running on a Windows Box.

Refer to this document and look for the section  (Collecting Data manually)
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21111364

This is typically required during a PMR process but you should be able to do the same and try and analyze the data that is captured.

If you cannot make progress after analyzing this data you should consider opening up a PMR.

if you notice the contents of this doc, it would indeed take thread dumps which would give insight to what the JVM is doing during these 100% CPU time.

HTH
Manglu

Comment: +1 for the help.

turns out the problem wasn't in the expected area, but some custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a thread dump to see what is going on with the login thread.

```
wsadmin
wsadmin>set jvm [$AdminControl completeObjectName type=JVM, process=server1,*]
wsadmin>$AdminControl invoke $jvm dumpThreads
```

Comment: +1 for the help.

turns out the problem wasn't in the expected area, but some custom code.